# Getting syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my code. I have checked everything but it is not working. I am running this script on azure devOps platform.

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is a comment!
aux_file="auxdate.txt"
if [[ ! -e "aux_file" || $(( ($(date '+%s') - $(cat aux_file))/(60*60*24) )) -ge 21 ]];
then
   echo $(date '+%s') > "aux_file"
    echo "Running"
    python cronjb.py
else
    echo "Not Running"
fi
```

Comment: This is propably an error with the platform because code is working

Comment: Yes, tried everything but the issue is same. It is perfectly working on my local.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh : Do you have a linefeed after the `fi`? Also check for possible unprintable characters in the script, in particular after the final `echo`. I would also verify the ASCII code of the double quotes around the _Not Running_.

Comment: Sure you're running it with bash and not sh? (Though that would likely show an error about `[[`)

Comment: You can use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to syntax check your scripts.

Comment: The code copied from the question does not suffer from the problem you're reporting.  Therefore, what you show is not what's causing the trouble.  Copying the code form the question back to your system might solve the issue.  You should also fix the three occurrences of the `$aux_file` vs `aux_file` discrepancy mentioned by newcomer [Daniel Malcor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2796871/daniel-malcor) who posted a comment as an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64841528/15168) — perhaps only visible to people with 10K rep.